# C# How to create/host a new SOAP Web Service that implements an existing WSDL & XSD contract

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I am provided with an existing .wsdl & .xsd file. I need to host a SOAP Web Service which uses these existing contracts, probably using interfaces. I tried to work my way using `wsdl.exe` & `svcutil.exe` to generate interface classes and then use WCF project to host a new Service on IIS, but I'm running out of luck.

Has someone done something like this in that past? Steps would help. Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  What you seek is known as _schema first_.  There is even a very nice tool that will generate skeleton code from a WSDL. https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wscfblue

Comment: I tried wscfblue but it didnt work that well for me.

Comment: Well perhaps try again